# How to turn a Classifier model into an image generator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have trained a classifier with this: https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/

Then I set up a python environment where I can run the model. I heard that with some tweaks such model could be turned into a deep dream like model. 
Does anyone know how I could tweak the model with keras to generate pictures that it learned co classify? Is it even possible?

Here is my current code:

```
import tensorflow.keras
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import numpy as np
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

# Disable scientific notation for clarity
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

# Load the model
model = tensorflow.keras.models.load_model('C:/Users/me/Downloads/keras_model.h5')

# Create the array of the right shape to feed into the keras model
# The 'length' or number of images you can put into the array is
# determined by the first position in the shape tuple, in this case 1.
data = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.float32)

# Replace this with the path to your image
image = Image.open('C:/Users/me/Downloads/0a8d8fa2c09ed00a54b6590f2fa01436.jpg')

#resize the image to a 224x224 with the same strategy as in TM2:
#resizing the image to be at least 224x224 and then cropping from the center
size = (224, 224)
image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

#turn the image into a numpy array
image_array = np.asarray(image)

# display the resized image
image.show()

# Normalize the image
normalized_image_array = (image_array.astype(np.float32) / 127.0) - 1

# Load the image into the array
data[0] = normalized_image_array

# run the inference
prediction = model.predict(data)
print(prediction)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is quite simple. you need to feed the image to the model and then maximize the activation of certain layers wrt the image itself not the weights of the model (changing the layers will change the result) 
tensorflow made an awesome notebook, check it out [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/generative/deepdream.ipynb#scrollTo=08KB502ONbGt) for more information and detailed examples